# How to calculate the emergent symmetry group in deconfined quantum critical point problem like $SO(3) \times Z_4 \to SO(5)$?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, group-theory, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

In the deconfined quantum criticality literatures like https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevX.9.041037, some equations are usually given: $$SO(3)\times Z_{4}\to SO(5),\\U(1)\times Z_{4}\to O(4),\\SO(3)\times Z_2 \to O(4),$$
but how to derive such relations?

It seems like the symmetries in the left hand side of above equations represent the symmetries of the phases in both sides of the transition points, such as the first line describe Neel-VBS transition, the order parameter of Neel phase has $SO(3)$ symmetry, and the VBS has $Z_4$ symmetry.

**Question**: Could anyone tell me how to derive above equations, and for example $U(1)\times Z_2$ ?

Comment: Looking at Table IV in the linked paper, the idea is that the effective action with the monopole terms in the second column only have the smaller symmetry on the left-hand side. However, at the phase transition, these terms are irrelevant, so you can drop them in the scaling limit (see Fig 8.a for example). Then in the absence of this term, one has the larger symmetry on the right. For a discussion of emergent symmetry at a critical point in a simpler context than DQCPs, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/510386/definition-of-dangerously-irrelevant-operator/511350#511350

Comment: @SethWhitsitt The linked paper? you mean Chubukov's paper?

Comment: Yes, if you look at Appendix B of the Chubukov paper, and begin reading at the paragraph starting "To clarify the issue, we now introduce a pedagogical discussion...", it described how one has Z_4 \rightarrow O(2) when describing Z_4 symmetry breaking in 3D. (You may want to ignore the nearby discussion about quantum antiferromagnets, which has now been superseded by the deconfined criticality scenario.)